# Problem with unique SQL query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want to select all records, but have the query only return a single record per Product Name.  My table looks similar to:

```
SellId   ProductName Comment
1          Cake        dasd 
2          Cake        dasdasd
3          Bread       dasdasdd
```

where the Product Name is not unique.  I want the query to return a single record per ProductName with results like:

```
SellId   ProductName Comment
1          Cake        dasd 
3          Bread       dasdasdd
```

I have tried this query,

```
Select distict ProductName,Comment ,SellId from TBL#Sells
```

but it is returning multiple records with the same ProductName.  My table is not realy as simple as this, this is just a sample.  What is the solution?  Is it clear?

Comment: What is the objective of your code? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Given more than one comment for cake, what do you want to see in the comment column for the single line returned for cake?

Comment: I want to select all records but Any Product Name shoudn't repeat in query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select  ProductName, 
min(Comment) , min(SellId) from TBL#Sells
group by ProductName
```

If y ou only want one record per productname, you ofcourse have to choose what value you want for the other fields.

If you aggregate (using group by) you can choose an `aggregate function`,
htat's a function that takes a list of values and return only one :  here I have chosen `MIN` : that is the smallest walue for each field.

NOTE :  comment and sellid can come from different records, since MIN is taken...

Othter aggregates you might find useful :

```
FIRST : first record encountered
LAST : last record encoutered
AVG : average 
COUNT : number of records
```

first/last have the advantage that all fields are from the same record.

Comment: I think he wants 'min' rather.

Comment: @leppie, indeed, changed it accordingly, tx

Comment: Thanks , I got my answer."Muchas Gracias"

Comment: The only thing I'd be careful of with this answer is that the COMMENT will not necessarily match the SELLID. Because you said your table is more complex, I would just watch that if you expect the values to be from matching rows. The MIN Comment could actually come from a different row to the SellId.

Comment: I think about this that with the query that **peter** wrote, the **productname** will be unique and don't repeat in the output result?

Comment: **I see a product more than one time in the result.but this is not what i want.**

Comment: @Lightwing : a product, do you mean a productname?

Comment: @gats : ofcourse, you should read the answer, I have mentionned that (after NOTE in capitals)

Comment: You mileage may vary, but doing min / max on char fields, especially long ones can be a performance killer.

Comment: @Peter apologies. Read the earlier version you posted and not the update. Not hacking on the response (in fact I upvoted it), just warning him.

Comment: @Gats : no problem at all, fields from different might not but ideal indeed, but he was not too clear about his goal.

Comment: Oh sorry guyz(Lo Siento).The answer is realy **True** and my new problem is about unicode Characters.Thanks again @Peter  **This question has ended here.**

Comment: @lightwing, This question has ended here --> come again?

Comment: This is definitely not the best answer. Also, I was wondering about `FIRST` and `LAST` aggregate. Never saw those in SQL server.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT S.ProductName, S.Comment, S.SellId
FROM
   Sells S
   JOIN (SELECT MAX(SellId)
        FROM Sells
        GROUP BY ProductName) AS TopSell ON TopSell.SellId = S.SellId
```

This will get the latest comment as your selected comment assuming that SellId is an auto-incremented identity that goes up.

Comment: Thanks , I got my answer."Muchas Gracias"

Comment: shouldn't we include product name in join ?

Comment: No because i've already got 1 id per name in the sub-query. Sub query gets the latest entry by product name and 1st part gets the rest of the details.

Answer (score 0):

I know, you've got an answer already, I'd like to offer a way that was fastest in terms of performance for me, in a similar situation. I'm assuming that SellId is Primary Key and identity. You'd want an index on ProductName for best performance.

```
select 
    Sells.* 
from 
(
    select 
        distinct ProductName 
    from 
        Sells
) x
join 
    Sells 
on 
    Sells.ProductName = x.ProductName
    and Sells.SellId =
    (
        select 
            top 1 s2.SellId 
        from 
            Sells s2 
        where 
            x.ProductName = s2.ProductName 
        Order By SellId
    )
```

A slower method, (but still better than Group By and MIN on a long char column) is this:

```
select 
    * 
from
(
    select 
        *,ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY ProductName order by SellId) OccurenceId 
    from sells
) x
where 
    OccurenceId = 1
```

An advantage of this one is that it's much easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table Sale
(
    SaleId int not null
        constraint PK_Sale primary key,
    ProductName varchar(100) not null,
    Comment varchar(100) not null
)

insert Sale
values
    (1, 'Cake', 'dasd'),
    (2, 'Cake', 'dasdasd'),
    (3, 'Bread', 'dasdasdd')

-- Option #1 with over()
select *
from Sale
where SaleId in
(
    select SaleId
    from
    (
        select SaleId, row_number() over(partition by ProductName order by SaleId) RowNumber
        from Sale
    ) tt
    where RowNumber = 1
)
order by SaleId

-- Option #2
select *
from Sale
where SaleId in
(
    select min(SaleId)
    from Sale
    group by ProductName
)       
order by SaleId

drop table Sale
```